Physical Explanation of Maximum Power Transfer
I have seen a lot of videos on this theorem but all of them prove it using algebra or calculus. When I tried to think of this problem in terms of the physical definition of power i.e energy transferred by electrons in one second, This entire theorem basically fell apart for me and I couldn't make any sense of it.
Also, is there any difference between interenal resistance and external resistance being equal and just two equal resistances connected in series both of which are 'external' (so basically bringing out the internal resistance as an external resistance connected in series with the the first one)?

You might want to state which resource you are using. At least as far as I know, the English terminology is not internal v.s. external resistance.

Are you asking why the power dissipated in the external circuit is greatest when the external resistance is equal to the internal resistance of the battery?

You didn’t say why it doesn’t make sense to you.

If you have a high current through a small voltage drop, a lot of electrons go through but each one loses only a small amount of energy, resulting in a small overall power delivered.
If you have a small current through a large voltage drop each electron that goes through loses a large amount of energy, but the number of electrons passing is small. So again the total power delivered is small.
If you have a medium amount of power and medium current, you get a higher power delivery than either of the extremes.
If you want to prove that the actual optimum happens when the load resistance equals the source resistance, then you have to break out the math.

is there any difference between interenal resistance and external resistance being equal and just two equal resistances connected in series both of which are 'external' (so basically bringing out the internal resistance as an external resistance connected in series with the the first one)?

In finding the maximum power transfer we treat the internal resistance as fixed (not something we can control) and the load resistance as a variable we can control. If we can control the internal resistance then we can increase power transfer by lowering the internal resistance (assuming we're using a voltage source rather than a current source), even if that means the load resistance is no longer equal.
If we're delivering power to some load through a network of resistors, then the Thevenin theorem tells us we can reduce that to an equivalent ideal voltage source and series resistor. To maximize power transfer without changing the delivery network, the power transfer theorem says we have to make the load resistor match the Thevenin equivalent series resistor of that system.

(so basically bringing out the internal resistance as an external resistance connected in series with the the first one)

The whole idea of an equivalent internal resistance is that we can treat whatever loss mechanisms exist in the source as a separate series resistor, when in fact they are actually various loss mechanisms such as chemical reaction rate limitations in a battery. We've already "brought the resistor outside" when we came up with the idea of an equivalent series resistor to account for the voltage drop due to loading the source.

To add just a little to Photon's detailed answer:
It is handy to remember that in all branches of dynamical analysis, power is always the product of an effort variable (like voltage or pressure) and a flow variable (like current or mass flow rate). Power transfer between subsystems is always maximized when the impedances (the current versus voltage characteristic) of both subsystems (source and load) are identical. In this matched-impedance case the power delivered to the load resistance is equal to the power dissipated in the internal resistance of the source.

First, instead of thinking in terms of “internal” and “external” resistances, think instead in terms of a fixed “source” resistance and a variable “load” resistance, respectively.
The source resistance is that typically inherent to the voltage source. An example is the internal resistance that is part of any real battery. The load resistance is a variable that depends on the properties of the device connected to the voltage source. It is electrically in series with the source resistance when connected to the source.
Next, with respect to power delivered to the load, think in terms of the product of current, i.e. coulombs of electrons per second to the load, times the voltage across the load, i.e. the work in joules per coulomb of electrons needed to move the electrons through the resistor. The product is joules per second, or power delivered to the load.
This power is maximum when the product of the voltage across the load and current through the load is a maximum, which is the case when the source and load resistances are equal.
Finally, don’t confuse max power transfer with maximum efficiency of power delivery.
While the maximum power transfer theorem means the source delivers maximum power to the load, it doesn’t mean power delivery is the most efficient. Indeed, when the source and load resistances are equal, only 50% of the power generated by the source is delivered to the load. The rest is dissipated in the source resistance.
Hope this helps.
